# how to delete rails log file after certain size

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a daemon that runs constantly which fills up the log file(development.log or production.log) pretty quickly. What is the best way to delete the log file after certain size or delete the portion before certain day.

Comment: You should edit your questing to specify what OS you're running on, and also add some more tags, as this is more OS specific than Rails specific.

Comment: Question more specifically requesting log rotation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation/4883967#4883967

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way is to set up log rotation, but how you do this is very platform dependent,
so you should add a comment about what you're using, both for development and production.

For our apps running on Linux, we have a file */etc/logrotate.d/appname* for each app,
that looks something like this:

```
/path/to/rails_root_for_app/log/production.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 7
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 640 capistrano capistrano
}
```

This will move the log into a new file once a day, keeping a compressed backup file for each
of the last 7 days.

If you just want to empty the file without keeping any of the data in it while the daemon is
running, simply do this from a shell:

```
> /path/to/rails_root_for_app/log/development.log
```

This will truncate the file to 0 bytes length.

Answer (score 14):

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.log_path, 50, 1.megabyte)
```

but beware that multiple mongrels can have issues with this.

Comment: This is the most correct answer from a strictly Rails specific point of view.

Comment: What does the 50 stand for?

Comment: 50 means 50 files. See shift_age http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html#method-c-new

Comment: Was just trying this. I had to change the syntax a bit. config.logger = Logger.new(config.paths['log'].first, 50, 1048576) because both config.log_path and 1.megabyte gave me errors.

Comment: @kirk try setting the log_path ```config.log_file = 'log/rpush.log'```

Answer (score 5):

I prefer a monthly log file in my production.rb file

```
config.logger = Logger.new(config.log_path, 'monthly')
```

Answer (score 1):

Or even better, if all your environments are on either Mac or Linux, and have /usr/sbin/rotatelogs, just use that. It's much more flexible, and doesn't have the data loss issue that logrotate has (even if you use copytruncate).

Add this inside config/application.rb (or just config/environments/production.rb if you only want rotation in prod):

```
log_pipe = IO.popen("/usr/sbin/rotatelogs #{Rails.root}/log/#{Rails.env}.%Y%m%d.log 86400", 'a')
config.logger = Logger.new(log_pipe)
```

(From [this blog post](http://roninonrails.blogspot.com/2008/04/auto-rotate-rails-log-files.html))

Answer (score 0):

Or you can delegate logging to [syslog](http://toolmantim.com/articles/logging_rails_to_syslog_with_sysloglogger)