# Benefit to maintaining development logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I have a development log for one of my projects that is now a text file in excess of 5GB in size. As this contains the logs from every query I've run for many months I feel the desire to delete/reduce it down a bit by eliminating some of the queries I did way back.

Are there any **considerations / drawbacks** in deleting old development logs? What do you do to deal with logs when they get big?

Comment: Simple consideration: Is there any possible circumstance you could imagine where you would need this data for anything?

Comment: Simple answer: no. There is no benefit!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I clear them from time to time, usually if the app have no errors and bugs for a month for ex, I truncate development logs cause I really don't see what's the point of them. When I make modifications I again keep the logs for a certain amount of time to see if any errors will pop up, if not, I delete them as well. 5GB of logs is way too much I think.

Here is a topic about how to set up log rotation:

[how to delete rails log file after certain size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036821/how-to-delete-rails-log-file-after-certain-size)

hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Think of your development log like a story of what recently happened.

That's what it's good for.

For instance, if something gets lost in the mix between Page A, clicking Button B, and landing on Page C, then your development log will tell that story.

I can't think of any conceivably purpose for having a 5 GB development log, much less "maintaining" a development log.

Use the log to narrow down and squash a problem you're having right now.