# Log rotation in Rails DEVELOPMENT mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, bash, logging

For a Rails 3.1 (will be 3.2 very soon), I have exceptionally verbose logs that have a lot of additional worker information spewing forth into them.

I routinely end up with multigigabyte `development.log` files.  I've seen some various chatter around about rotating production logs, however I've not found anything that seems applicable to `development.log` rotation.

**How do you rotate your `development.log` at every `100.megabytes` or so?**  OR WHAT I WOULD PREFER is to actually truncate the head of the file so that only the most recent items remain in the log, up to 100MB of the most recent entries.

I have played with this a little and am thinking more and more than nothing quite like this exists at present and that perhaps I should implement something that will use the ruby `File.truncate` somehow, however I'm not sure of the efficacy of this yet on the tail end of the file as of yet.

Comment: Running on Mac OS X for `development`.  Some are on linux in the group.  If I can use a non-specific method that would be best, or I can do something with `case CONFIG['host_os']` if necessary.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036821/how-to-delete-rails-log-file-after-certain-size

Comment: I just clarified it a little.  My real goal here is to KEEP the tail of the file, or the MOST RECENT log entries, discarding the oldest ones.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the above possible solution or temporary work around?

Comment: production question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883891/ruby-on-rails-production-log-rotation

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can actually tell the Ruby Logger class to rotate the files in the constructor:

http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Logger.html#M000163

Example:

```
Logger.new(name, shift_age = 7, shift_size = 1048576)
```

In one of my enrivornment files I have the following line:

```
config.logger = Logger.new("#{RAILS_ROOT}/log/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}.log", 10, 1048576)
```

This keeps the last 10 logfiles which are rotated every 1 MB.

Comment: This works nicely, however in 3.2 the Logger class is deprecated in favor of ActiveSupport::BufferedLogger, which apparently does not support rotation. Frustrating!

Comment: @CaffeineComa can you support your inference? I'm using Rails 3.2.2 and this works pretty well, at least in development mode, that is the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

On OSX i would use newsyslog

[/etc/newsyslog.conf](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man8/newsyslog.8.html)

On a Linux OS: logrotate

[logrotate](http://linux.die.net/man/8/logrotate)

Comment: Any thoughts on using `tail -c $[100*1024*1024] development.log`?

Comment: well tbh not really, its pretty massive.  I normally (for debugging / devlopment) clear my console (cmd-k) and then run my code to see what happened. Watching a 100 MB trace, no thank you :) And it depends as well if other people are running on your dev env. Since then you need to split the clutter of the different IP's.

Comment: Hahahah, yeah, that's still a bit large.  Once we don't have such crazy fire hose spew going on for some data I'll trim it down to something more like 10MB probably.